How to undersatnd below CompletableFuture code?
I have a below code, but not wrk as I expectd:
public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture<String> cfQuery = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return "Hello";
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        CompletableFuture<Double> cfFetch = cfQuery.thenApplyAsync((code) -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return 5 + Math.random() * 20;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        cfFetch.thenAccept((result) -> {
            System.out.println("price: " + result);
        });
        cfFetch.join();
        try {
            System.out.println(cfFetch.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

Why only System.out.println("price: " + result); only output one time ?
try to debug but fund no clue

You have started one task and this task will get performed. Asking for the result a second time does not launch a new task. It’s still one task, no matter how often you ask for the result.

@Holger Correct, thx
